# Filter Django Queryset Based on URL Parameter

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models - one for tools and one for parts.  The list page will be identical.  Can I filter what is shown in the template based on URL?

**Views** *(I'd like to combine tool_list and part_list into product_list)*

```
def tool_list(request):
    tools = Tool.objects.all()
    parts = Part.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tool_list.html', {'tools': tools, 'parts': parts})


def part_list(request):
    parts = Part.objects.all()
    tools = Tool.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tool_list.html', {'parts': parts, 'tools': tools})


def product_detail(request, **kwargs):
    tool = get_object_or_404(Tool,  slug=kwargs.get('slug'))
    part = get_object_or_404(Part)
    return render(request, 'product_detail.html', {'tool': tool, 'part': part})
```

**url**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^products/tools/$', tool_list, name='tool_list'),
    url(r'^products/parts-supplies/$', part_list, name='part_list'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<category>[^\.]+)/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

Comment: Do you want two different urls for a single view?

Comment: Yes, I want `products/tools...` and `products/parts-supplies...` but using the same view template. And, based in the `URL`, the queryset would be either tools or parts.  Now that I think of it, the only way to do this might be to put conditional statements in my template to check for url.

Answer (score 1):

Your two views, `tool_list` and `part_list` are exact replicas of each other. You can create a single view and route multiple urls to it. Like this

```
def product_list(request):
    tools = Tool.objects.all()
    parts = Part.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tool_list.html', {'tools': tools, 'parts': parts})
```

In your urls:

```
url(r'^products/tools/$', product_list, name='tool_list'),
url(r'^products/parts-supplies/$', product_list, name='part_list'),
```